# REST service with binary data

Tags: java, rest, service, binary-data

I want to create Restful service which can accept binary data.
I've implemented **javax.xml.ws.Provider** interface, but i can't get content of request. If I use **javax.xml.ws.Dispatch** then its send only XML data, but I need transfer binary data.

Please give some solution, but I don't prefer to use JAX-RS or Restlets.

Thanks.

Comment: Please close or delete this question.
For REST service I must use JAX-RS. And I did it by using Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell javax.xml.ws.Provider is a class that is part for [Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) which is a SOAP based framework.  That might explain why you are having difficult using it to create a REST service.

I can only suggest that you ask this question to people who know Axis. I will retag your question.  That might help.

Comment: I'm sorry Darrel, but I'll retag question, because javax.xml.ws.Provider is not Axis2's class, it is part of Java 6.

Comment: Ok so assuming you are talking about this class http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Provider.html it is still SOAP based and nothing to do with REST.